# How can I make the menu bars adhere to the Ambiance theme?

Tags: themes, gtk, ambiance

- Xubuntu 13.10

I chose `Ambiance` as a theme and it doesn't seem to work for all elements of the GUI/DE:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'd like to make the DE/GUI look coherent and "light", just as the rest of the Ambiance theme. How could I do that?

**edit** I am *not* talking about Radiance, its light counterpart.